# dplyr: reshape wide to long

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

```
HAVE = data.frame("STUDENT"=c(1, 2, 3),
"CLASS"=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
"SCORE1"=c(50, 79, 61),
"SCORE2"=c(74, 100, 70),
"SCORE3"=c(78, 65, 87),
"TEST1"=c(80, 96, 93),
"TEST2"=c(59, 57, 89),
"TEST3"=c(63, 53, 92))


WANT = data.frame("STUDENT"=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
"CLASS"=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'),
"SEMESTER"=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
"SCORE"=c(50, 74, 78, 79, 100, 65, 61, 70, 87),
"TEST"=c(80, 59, 63, 96, 57, 53, 93, 89, 92))
```

Trial-

```
WANT = tidyr::pivot_longer(HAVE, cols = -c("STUDENT", "CLASS"), names_to = c('SEMESTER', '.value'),
names_prefix = c("SCORE", "TEST"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need the `names_sep` or `names_pattern` to find the delimiter in the column names.  Here, the column names should be split between the non-digit (`\\D`) and a digit (`\\d`) - we use regex lookaround for that (or use `names_pattern = "^(\\D+)(\\d+)$")` to capture the characters)

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(HAVE, cols = -c(STUDENT, CLASS),
    names_to = c(".value", "SEMESTER"), names_sep = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  STUDENT CLASS SEMESTER SCORE  TEST
    <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1 A     1           50    80
2       1 A     2           74    59
3       1 A     3           78    63
4       2 B     1           79    96
5       2 B     2          100    57
6       2 B     3           65    53
7       3 C     1           61    93
8       3 C     2           70    89
9       3 C     3           87    92
```

Answer (score 3):

Here with `names_pattern` and with regex: `(\\w+)(\\d)`:

- `\\w+`... One or more(+) word character. A word character is a letter, a number, or an underscore. This set of characters may also be represented by the regex character set [a-zA-Z0-9_]
- '\d'... One digit

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(HAVE, 
                    cols = -c(STUDENT, CLASS),
                    names_to = c('.value', 'Semester'), 
                    names_pattern = '(\\w+)(\\d)')
```

```
  STUDENT CLASS Semester SCORE  TEST
    <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1       1 A     1           50    80
2       1 A     2           74    59
3       1 A     3           78    63
4       2 B     1           79    96
5       2 B     2          100    57
6       2 B     3           65    53
7       3 C     1           61    93
8       3 C     2           70    89
9       3 C     3           87    92
```